# Too many redirects with own login form - Spring Security

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security

I would like to make own login form. When I'm changing login page I can't open it. Google Chrome told me that there is too many redirects to this page...

My code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginPage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/loginError", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginErrorPage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login");
    modelAndView.addObject("error", "true");
    modelAndView.addObject("msg", "invalid login credentials");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

settings:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/index").failureUrl("/loginError");
}
```

and login form:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:if test="${error eq 'true'}">
    ${msg}
</c:if>
<form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
      method='POST'>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="submit" type="submit"
                       value="submit" />
            </td>
            <td><input name="reset" type="reset" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you tell me where is the problem? I studied a lot of tutorials but always the same problem. To many redirects...

BTW. IntelliJ cant resolve: j_spring_security_chec

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As stated in the manual you need to permit requests to the login page otherwise it will just go into an endless loop:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form

> We must grant all users (i.e. unauthenticated users) access to our log
>   in page. The formLogin().permitAll() method allows granting access to
>   all users for all URLs associated with form based log in.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index").failureUrl("/loginError");       
}
```

Comment: I also found that it could be added via the xml as well.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-http